# F# class Explicit Fields and DefaultValue

Tags: f#

This is an F# language-definition question.
I was wondering why F# can not automatically deduce Explicit Fields in the first place? And then DefaultValue automatically as well ...

Why have another class syntax (so many of them in F#)... where instead a `let` bound field without a value (but with a type) could be interpreted automatically as (the meaning of) `val`. Furthermore when a DefaultValue is needed along side a default constructor, why not just deduce it automatically?

`let myInt1 : int` 
interpreted as the meaning of: 
`val myInt1 : int` 
or 
`[<DefaultValue>] val myInt : int`

Lastly (could be a different topic, and therefore please consider it as a minor inquiry), why explicit fields (or public fields) require a self identifier reference within member methods? Again the class implementation syntax looses a lot of its simplicity.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll get an authoritative answer here. If I were you, I would open an issue on uservoice and see what the response would be.

Comment: A language should make the common operations simple and the uncommon possible. Explicit fields are an uncommon thing in my book - I can't even think of a situation where I felt the need to use the explicit class definition syntax over the implicit one. Therefore it makes sense to me to *not* optimize for the uncommon scenario.

Comment: Adding to @scrwtp : F# is functional-first language. Classes are rarely used in F# programs - mostly for interop with other .NET languages.

Comment: I am not disputing your claims, just mentioning that as F# becomes more mainstream, development e.g. with Xamarin requires you to live within/alongside .NET classes (at least to some degree). Therefore it may make sense to consider it. But again, I am grateful to learn from your comments. Many thanks.

Comment: Also if some of the syntax decisions in class definitions looks awkward or wrong you can create an issue on GutHub F# project as @FyodorSoikin suggested. F# is open sourced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't claim to understand *all* of your question.

Explicit fields can naturally not be inferred from the value because there is no value; it is uninitialised. So you need to give a type.

`let myInt : int` doesn't really make sense, because let needs a value.

I agree with you on the last point, the val could just as easily be in scope and not require `this` qualifier, subject to normal shadowing rules.

Answer (score 0):

Was curious how you would force initialization of a `val mutable` field:

```
type MyClass private () =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable v:int

    new (v:int) as this = MyClass() then this.v <- v
```

This makes the primary constructor private so that the `new (v:int)` must be used. The form of `new (v:int) as this` definition lets you first call the primary constructor and initialize the `val mutable` using `then ... this.v <- ...`

The [F# language reference on constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors) was most helpful.